# Vibrating an Android phone based on mic input

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, microphone, android-vibration

I want to record the voice/sound input from the android phone and convert to specific type of vibrations of the phone. The idea is to help differently abled people with their surrounding environment and help in giving some sense of nearby obstacles (say car etc). How can I :

1. Read the mic / sound input and save it in real-time ( to process it  further).
2. Vibrate the phone with specific frequency

I am looking for the specific libraries and some sample codes to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Im fairly certain the vibrator doesnt function with frequencys, its either on or its off. The best you could do is probably morse code.